# B’racha achrona on sunflower seeds?

Tags: halacha, blessing, food

If one eats a k’zayit of sunflower seeds including the flavored shell, which he spits out, but less than a k’zayit of the seeds themselves, which he swallows, does he need to say an after b’racha?

Comment: Absolutely no! The bracha acharona is for the swallowed quantity